# On Facebook, is there a way to not display the exact time of posting?

Tags: facebook

Short question is: if I post on Facebook, can I omit the part about posting at 2:30am, but just "Posted June 3, 2020"?

---

Details:

Sometimes I am too tired after work, so I may sleep around 6pm and then wake up around 2am.

Then I may play a little Animal Crossing on the Nintendo Switch.  Sometimes I did something great, such as able to fish a whale shark.  Now that's no crime, but if I post to Facebook as a public post, I don't want my coworkers and managers, being able to see it some day, think or have the judgment that "wow this guy is playing Animal Crossing at 2:30am... hm..."

I think the same with the situation: if we went through some tough time to fix something on the website during a workday, deployed it, and now I have a coffee break at 3:30pm for 15 minutes and I played some Animal Crossing, and there is a post I wanted to post on my profile and also share with a Facebook Animal Crossing group, is there a way to post it as "June 5, 2020, 3:35pm" which might give a wrong impression about "what is he doing during a workday?"

I think it is related to privacy, and it is to avoid shallow judgment by others. Also, some people may not want people to find out information about themselves such as "seems like he is not at home at a certain time."

So I hope to have the post, at least after a few days, just to say, "Posted June 3, 2020" instead of "Posted June 3, 2020, at 2:30am". Is that possible?

Answer (score 1):

It's not possible to hide the time the post was made on Facebook. Displaying the exact time of posting is a fundamental feature of the site. If you hover over the short timestamp, a pop-up will show the exact time of posting. It also acts as a permalink for the post.

[image: short timestamp]

You should consider hiding the posts you're worried about from your coworkers instead. Facebook allows you to organise your friends into groups and you can exclude any groups you want every time you post. Facebook will remember your setting so you don't have to select the same groups every time. For instance, I hide all my posts by default from the group "Acquaintances":

[image: exclude group when posting]

Comment: so if I do want to make a post public to the world, but don't want my coworkers or manager to get the wrong impression, the choice is not to make it public to the world